# How to pass the variable value into the url in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass the variable value into the url but unable to pass ,in alert i am getting the value but when i place the same variable in the url the value is not taking.

```
i have tried in the following way:

code:
----------------------

    {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js')} 
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/js/functions.js')} 
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')} 
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/ui/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js')} 
   {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/postmessage/jquery.ba-postmessage.js')} 
   {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/bbq/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js')} 
requireCssFile('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css');


function requireCssFile(filename) 
 { 

   var fileref = document.createElement('link'); 
   fileref.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet'); 
   fileref.setAttribute('type', 'text/css'); 
   fileref.setAttribute('href', filename);  
 } 
   alert('hi');
   var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
   alert('hi1'); 
   var param = "{!customobj__c.Id}"; 
   alert(param);
   var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/pagename?id=param")}';
   alert(iframe_url);
   var j$modalDialog = j$('<div id="opppopup"></div>') 
   .html('<iframe id="iframeContentId" src="' + iframe_url + '" frameborder="0"   height="100%" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" />') 
.dialog({ 
           autoOpen: false, 
           autoclose: true,
           resizable: true, 
           width: 300, 
           height: 100, 
           autoResize: true, 
           modal: true, 
           draggable: true 
        }); 

    j$modalDialog.dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

You kept the 'param' variable inside the double quotes(") because of this it is considered as a string literal instead of variable.

You need to split the variable out of double quotes in below manner:

```
var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/pagename?id="+param)}';
```

Comment: var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/pagename?id="'+param+')}'; try this

Comment: even though no use